# Get dataset from rdlc file from code

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I need to get the SQL query from the rdlc file to run on my database and add a datasource for Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport with results of the query.

I used the code from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3e15701-c6fd-4c70-991f-5d58c4b4970e/get-parameters-and-datasets-from-rdlc-at-runtime?forum=vsreportcontrols) to work with the report data. But

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport
```

doesn't have dataset getters.

rdlc file contains DatasetInfo for DataSet in DataSets section

```
<DataSets>
  <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
    <Query>
      <DataSourceName>Dataset1</DataSourceName>
      <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
    </Query>
    <Fields> Some Fields description here
    </Fields>
    <rd:DataSetInfo>
      <rd:DataSetName>Dataset1</rd:DataSetName>
      <rd:SchemaPath>c:\Dataset1.xsd</rd:SchemaPath>
      <rd:TableName>bAPCD</rd:TableName>
      <rd:TableAdapterFillMethod>Fill</rd:TableAdapterFillMethod>
      <rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod>GetData</rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod>
      <rd:TableAdapterName>bAPCDTableAdapter</rd:TableAdapterName>
    </rd:DataSetInfo>
  </DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

The .xsd file contains the SQL query I need

```
<DbSource ConnectionRef="DBConnection (Web.config)" DbObjectName="dbconnect.dbo.bAPCD" DbObjectType="Table" FillMethodModifier="Public" FillMethodName="Fill" GenerateMethods="Both" GenerateShortCommands="true" GeneratorGetMethodName="GetData" GeneratorSourceName="Fill" GetMethodModifier="Public" GetMethodName="GetData" QueryType="Rowset" ScalarCallRetval="System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" UseOptimisticConcurrency="false" UserGetMethodName="GetData" UserSourceName="Fill">

            <SelectCommand>
              <DbCommand CommandType="Text" ModifiedByUser="false">
                <CommandText>SELECT * FROM dbo.ttable</CommandText>
                <Parameters />
              </DbCommand>
            </SelectCommand>
</DbSource>
```

How can I get the SQL query from this file in the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the select sql :

```
var dataset = new MyDataTable(); //RPTDatasets.MySet.MyDataTable
var adapter = new bAPCDTableAdapter(); //RPTDatasets.MySet.MySet.Designer

string commandText = adapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText.ToString();
```

//or change command

```
 adapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FOO";
 adapter.Fill(dataset.MyTable);
```